# How to get rewrited name of cusom taxonomy?

Tags: custom-post-types

I have registered custom post taxonomy with rewrited name:

```
register_taxonomy('behold_gallery-albums-subject', 'behold_gallery',array(
    'hierarchical'              => true,
    'labels'                    => $labels,
    'show_ui'                   => true,
    'show_admin_column'         => true,
    'rewrite'                   => array( 'slug' => 'kategorie-galerii', 'with_front' => true ),
    'update_count_callback'     => '_update_post_term_count',
    'query_var'                 => true,
));
```

so name of my custom taxonomy is 'behold_gallery-albums-subject' but is rewrited to 'kategorie-galerii'.

If I want to get name of this taxonomy, I can use this

```
$postsTaxonomy = get_sub_field('archive__post-choose-taxonomy'); // ACF
$postsTerm = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); 
$postsTerm_id = $postsTerm->term_id;
$PostsTaxName = get_taxonomy($postsTaxonomy)->labels->name;
```

but how can I get this rewrited name, not the 'original'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean just get the rewritten slug? From the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_taxonomy/) it looks like you should be able to do:

`$rewrite_name = get_taxonomy($postsTaxonomy)->rewrite['slug']`

Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Yes, I need slug. But your code doesn't work and I've tried it before. In this case $rewrite_name = get_taxonomy($postsTaxonomy)->rewrite; print_r($rewrite_name); I see the array content and my slug name. So your code should work - am I right?

Comment: yes, and it sounds like it is working if you see an array, you just need to add the ->slug on the end to get the slug name

Comment: Of course, I've added '-> slug', but I don't see any rewrited slug name... and that's the issue. So - in array I see it, but with $rewrite_name = get_taxonomy($postsTaxonomy)->rewrite->slug; echo $rewrite_name; I don't.

Comment: can you add to your question what you see when you do `print_r($rewrite_name);`

Comment: oh, sorry i just realised, it's an array, not another object. i'll update the answer

Comment: try that `['slug']` instead of `->slug`

Comment: Bingo! This is what Im missed :D thank u!